# Parse this string

Tags: sql, parsing, substring

What are the other ways to we parse this:

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE(DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @t(DESCRIPTION)

SELECT '1/8 qwe dfg asd asd' UNION ALL

SELECT '1/2 dfg asd qwe asd' UNION ALL

SELECT '1/2 asd dfg qwe asd' UNION ALL

SELECT '1/2 qwe asd asd rtq'

SELECT * FROM @t
```

/* Output : */

```
--1/8 qwe

--1/2 dfg

--1/2 asd

--1/2 qwe
```

Don't use fixed lenght, maybe charindex or something :)

Comment: create a select statement that will give the desired ouput

Comment: `What are the other ways...` – and what are the ways you've got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
substring (description,
           1,
           charindex (' ',
                      description,
                      charindex(' ', description)+1
                     )-1
          )
```

(I can't test it as I don't have access to SQL Server).

Comment: i forgot to give more details, you shouldn't use a fixed lenght, maybe charindex.

Comment: I already have one, but I just dont like how I've done it: 
SELECT SUBSTRING( DESCRIPTION , 1 ,  CHARINDEX(SPACE(1) ,  REPLACE(DESCRIPTION , SUBSTRING(DESCRIPTION , 1 , CHARINDEX(' ',DESCRIPTION)) , '') ) + LEN( SUBSTRING(DESCRIPTION , 1 ,  CHARINDEX(SPACE(1),DESCRIPTION)) ) ) FROM @t

Comment: @someonewhowillnotbemiss: It doesn't seem too late to add those details (along with the *actual question*) to your original post. You shouldn't rely on people reading all the comments. If the details are important, they must be immediately accessible.

Comment: This should really be simple, guess my brain just doesn't function correctly right now though :)

Comment: @Tony, nice, I just have to adjust  some expressions, like SELECT substring (description, 1,  charindex (' ', description , charindex( ' ' , description) +1)-1 ) FROM @t